# how to Emit the output even if the pattern did not matched

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

Is it possible for Flink's CEP library to emit the data per input received? even if there is not any pattern matched?
for example suppose there is this pattern

```
pattern: ba
input stream: a b a a
expect output stream is: F F T F
```

the default behavior is like this:

```
_ _ T _ 
_ = times that there is not any output.
```

the simplest solution that comes to my mind is left joining the input with output stream (there is not any left join on streams in flink and I should prepare it by coFlatMap) and mapping to the output (chang Nones with the value and drop the input) but I do not know if is it a good solution (performance-wise) or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union` [1] to combine the input (or a transformed version of the input) with the result coming from CEP. Note that for this to work, all of the DataStreams being unioned must have the same type.

[1] https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/#union

Comment: Thanks, I want to have an output per input (not more or less) for example if there is a signal I want to return T and otherwise I want to return F, I don't think the union can help to create that output except there is some way to remove the duplicated events (one with F that is generated from input and T that is generated from pattern detection output.)

Comment: Then I'll suggest you do a join (as you proposed). The easiest way to get this done will be to use MATCH_RECOGNIZE to do the pattern matching, and then do a SQL join.